# Angularjs to php giving http status code 405

Tags: php, angularjs, https, cors, http-status-code-405

So I'm trying to setup a simple feedback form in Angular that will send an email using php on the backend.  The problem is that I keep getting the following error:

```
POST https://localhost/mailer/contact-form.php 405 (Method Not Allowed)

405 Method Not Allowed
The method POST is not allowed for this resource.
You cannot POST a file
```

I *think* it has something to do with CORS, but don't know if it's more related to HTTPS since we are running on https://localhost for development.

Here's what I think is the important portion of the controller:

```
testControllers.controller('FeedbackCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

  $scope.feedback_errors = "";
  $scope.hasError = false;
  $scope.resultMessage;
  $scope.formData = {};
  $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
  $scope.submitted = false; //used so that form errors are shown only after the form has been submitted

  var param = function(data) {
    var returnString = '';
    for (var d in data){
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(d))
        returnString += d + '=' + data[d] + '&';
    }
    // Remove last ampersand and return
    return returnString.slice( 0, returnString.length - 1 );
  };

  $scope.submit = function(feedbackForm) {
    $scope.submitted = true;
    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
    if (feedbackForm.$valid) {
      $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : 'mailer/contact-form.php',
        data    : param($scope.formData),
        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
      }).success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        if (data.success) {
          $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
          $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
        } else {
          $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
          $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
        }
      });
    } else {
      $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
    }
  }
}]);
```

and here is the php:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');

$errors = array();
$data = array();
if (empty($_POST['comments']))
$errors['comments'] = 'Feedback is required.';
if ( ! empty($errors)) {
  $data['success'] = false;
  $data['errors'] = $errors;
  $data['messageError'] = 'Please check the fields in red';
} else {
  $data['success'] = true;
  $data['messageSuccess'] = 'Thanks for providing valuable feedback to the VIVA team.';
  $email_to = "jknowles@intellisis.com";
  $email_subject = "Feedback from VIVA webapp";
  $name = $_POST['firstname'] . ' ' . $_POST['lastname'];
  $email_from = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['comments']; // required
  $email_message = "Form details below.nn";
  $email_message .= "Name: ".$name."n";
  $email_message .= "Email: ".$email_from."n";
  $email_message .= "Message: ".$message."n";
  $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."rn".
  'Reply-To: '.$email_from."rn" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
}
// return all our data to an AJAX call
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I've tried so many different combinations for the header of the php file and one thing I'm wondering is if I'm missing something on the front end?  Any help will be immensely appreciated as I've been banging my head against the wall for hours.

Best Regards,
Julie

**EDIT**:

So I've created a simple form using Angular and I run it on one of my own servers and it works fine.

Here are response headers from both the one that works and the one that doesn't work:

**DOESN'T WORK**

```
General:
  Remote Address:xx.xx.xx.xx:yyy
  Request URL:https://xx.xx.xx.xx/form_test/processForm.php
  Request Method:POST
  Status Code:405 Not Allowed
Response Headers
  Connection:keep-alive
  Content-Length:574
  Content-Type:text/html
  Date:Mon, 06 Apr 2015 18:44:20 GMT
  Server:nginx/1.6.2
```

**WORKS**

```
General:
  Remote Address:xx.xx.xx.xx:yyy
  Request URL:http://juliemarie.me/form_test/processForm.php
  Request Method:POST
  Status Code:200 OK
Response Headers
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
  Connection:Keep-Alive
  Content-Type:text/html
  Date:Mon, 06 Apr 2015 18:37:19 GMT
  Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=100
  Server:Apache
  Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

It almost seems like the php file isn't even accessed.  Is that possible?

Comment: The angular `$http.post()` code looks fine - to rule out the CORS possibility, have you tried `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")`?

Comment: Yes Ed, I sure did.  That was the first thing I tried before hardcoding it to https://localhost.

Comment: To judge the problem, I suggest you to test 2 points as follows.

1. If you use only simple html form without angularjs(using ajax) and post the form, how is the result?

2. If you use simple HTTP (not HTTPS) server, how is the result?

Comment: Okay, I'll give those a shot yazaki, thanks!